# Running maven compile goal twice

Tags: maven, compilation

Working with a multi-module maven project. If i run following commands

```
mvn clean compile
mvn test
```

Project gets compiled twice as `test` also runs compile phase. How to run tests separately then compile?

Comment: Have you checked the log output?

Comment: It does compile twice. Have updated the question.

Comment: Please post the full log ....

Comment: Could you also explain _why_ you want to separate that?

Comment: Using maven with Jenkins CI/CD pipeline which shows each step as separate check right from GitHub PR page. Implementing life cycle in steps would specifically point to phase which failed the build. Ex: Was there a compilation error or Unit Tests failed.\n
**Implementing it this way would also work:**
`mvn clean install -DskipTests` - compilation works fine, also ready for deployment
`mvn surefire:test` - some way to run Unit Tests but not compile twice
`mvn deploy -DskipTests -Dmaven.install.skip=True` - runs deploy phase without again installing